# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/compose/runtime/internal/LiveLiteralKt

Tags: android, gradle, android-jetpack-compose

I am working on an app I created in Android studio using New Project>Empty Activity. The app uses Jetpack Compose although I have not added any ui code yet. I only added domain classes. The app was working but all of a sudden it stopped. When I try to run a main method, I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/compose/runtime/internal/LiveLiteralKt
    at com.chaluchukwu.math_util.parsing.LiveLiterals$ParserKt.String$arg-0$call-println$fun-main(Parser.kt)
    at com.chaluchukwu.math_util.parsing.ParserKt.main(Parser.kt:173)
    at com.chaluchukwu.math_util.parsing.ParserKt.main(Parser.kt)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: androidx.compose.runtime.internal.LiveLiteralKt
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 3 more
```

Here's my build.gradle.kts(:app)

```
plugins {
    id("com.android.application")
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android")
}

android {
    namespace = "com.chaluchukwu.math_util"
    compileSdk = 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId = "com.chaluchukwu.math_util"
        minSdk = 26
        targetSdk = 27
        versionCode = 1
        versionName = "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner = "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary = true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            isMinifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles(
                getDefaultProguardFile("proguard-android-optimize.txt"),
                "proguard-rules.pro"
            )
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose = true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.5.3"
    }
    packaging {
        resources {
            excludes += "/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0")
    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1")
    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.2")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")
    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
}
```

build.gradle.kts(Math-Util):

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.
plugins {
    id("com.android.application") version "8.1.0" apply false
    id("org.jetbrains.kotlin.android") version "1.9.10" apply false
}
```

Comment: I think version compatability is the issue. You must use same version for ```compileOptions``` and ```kotlinOptions```. I suggest you to use VERSION_1_7

Comment: @ChiragThummar that didn't work. I think it's a dependency issue. Besides this exact setup was working before.

Comment: Note that for Java compilers usually the source level can not be higher than the target level. So VERSION_17 for source and VERSION_1_8 will not really work well.

Comment: @Robert it does work

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the problem. After raising the min Sdk Version and the target Sdk Version, it started working again.
In build.gradle.kts(:app):

```
 minSdk = 29
 targetSdk = 29
```